# file:// prefix is missing in the returned URI of navigator.camera.getPicture

Tags: javascript, cordova

My cordova mobile app has a file chooser which uses the following code:

```
   navigator.camera.getPicture(photoCapturedSuccess(fileURI), 
            photoCapturedFail,
           {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
            correctOrientation: true
        });
```

the `fileURI` that is returned from `navigator.camera.getPicture()` was like `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20041615_135137.jpg`
Everything was working fine but one day the feature stopped working. On debugging code I found that the `fileURI` is missing the `file://` prefix.
ie. the URI now starts with  `/storage/emulated`
Any clue what happened?

Thanks

Comment: have u updated plugin?

Comment: yes. earlier it was org.apache.cordova.camera and org.apache.cordova.file.  Now on update I got cordova-plugin-camera  and cordova-plugin-file. Is that the reason?

Comment: `org.apache.cordova.camera` and `cordova-plugin-camera` both are same